# How to get UTC time

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, time, utc

I'm programming a small little program to download the appropriate set of files to be used by a meteorological software package. The files are in format like `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYYMMDD HHMM` in UTC. I want to know the current time in UTC in *C++* and I'm on Ubuntu. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Can you restate the question: do you want to _reformat_ the filenames from UTC to local?  Or do you want to _access_ current time as UTC?

Comment: Just access the current time in UTC, sorry for the confusion, I'll edit the question.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A high-end answer in C++ is to use Boost Date_Time.

But that may be overkill. The C library has what you need in `strftime`, the manual page has an example.

```
/* from man 3 strftime */

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    char outstr[200];
    time_t t;
    struct tm *tmp;
    const char* fmt = "%a, %d %b %y %T %z";

    t = time(NULL);
    tmp = gmtime(&t);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        perror("gmtime error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (strftime(outstr, sizeof(outstr), fmt, tmp) == 0) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "strftime returned 0");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    printf("%s\n", outstr);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); 
}
```

I added a full example based on what is in the manual page:

```
$ gcc -o strftime strftime.c 
$ ./strftime
Mon, 16 Dec 13 19:54:28 +0000
$
```

Comment: The strftime manpage example uses localtime() though. OP will need gmtime() in its stead to get the UTC time.

Comment: Using strftime appears to be the best looking option. Thanks. I can convert to UTC manually if necessary, but I want to look into what nos said.

Comment: @nos How would I account for DST using gmtime()?

Comment: @JasonMills There's no DST with UTC. time(NULL); should return the correct thing which you can pass to gmtime();

Comment: @JasonMills: (a) `gmtime` gives you UTC, not GMT, and UTC is agnostic of any time zones; (b) GMT is a single timezone anyway. :) The UK switches into BST when DST is applied.

Comment: I added a full example.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for reminding me, I don't know why I didn't realise that immediately,

Answer (score 9):

You can use gmtime:

```
struct tm * gmtime (const time_t * timer);
Convert time_t to tm as UTC time
```

Here's an example:

```
std::string now()
{
  std::time_t now= std::time(0);
  std::tm* now_tm= std::gmtime(&now);
  char buf[42];
  std::strftime(buf, 42, "%Y%m%d %X", now_tm);
  return buf;
}
```

Output:

```
20131220 19:33:51
```

ideone link: http://ideone.com/pCKG9K

Comment: You should use `std::strftime(buf, sizeof buf, ...)`. It's also worth noting that the `return buf;` is valid only because the value is implicitly converted to a `std::string`; if `now` returned a `char*` (as it likely would in C), you'd be returning a pointer to a local object, which is a big no-no.

Comment: Note: if possible you might want to use `gmtime_r` instead, which whilst non-standard, is both re-entrant and data-race safe.

Comment: @MatthieuM. you're correct, I would normally have a check for the existence of gmtime_r. I thought it was overkill for this answer. Thanks for useful feedback.